# Create tab programmatically

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm using material tabs as explained [here](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview). I'm having hard time trying to figure out how to programatically create (and then focus to) new tabs. I would also like to remove tabs when they are not needed anymore. By digging in the web I started guessing some function calls like

```
export class VehiclesComponent {

  @ViewChild(MdTabsModule) tabs: MdTabsModule;

  constructor (private router: Router, private parentComponent: AdminComponent, private userService: VehicleService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    /* code presented here for demonstration purposes */
    this.tabs.push({label: "Some new tab", content: '<b>New tab content</b>'});
  }
}
```

Of course this code is totally made up and it doesn't work. At least now I know that MdTabsModule doesn't have method named push. Unfortunately documentation is very scares. Creating tabs via TypeScript is not even remotely mentioned; Checking source code also didn't reveal such functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be easy. You can use `*ngFor` in your component.html.

Lets say you have a object MyTabs:

```
class MyTabs {
    Label: string;
    Contents: string;
}
```

Create am array of this class in your component class e.g.

```
myTabs: MyTabs [];
```

Then in your component.html, iterate over myTabs to create dynamic tabs.

Have a look here: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/tabs/tabs-demo.html